# How to speed up Magento 2 Store on Mobile

Tags: magento2, mobile, pagespeed

How to increase the Speed of store on **Phone** on *PageSpeed Insights* its only shows **15%** of performance on Phone but on PC it shows **64%** I also changed *Marge JS Files* and *Marge Css files* but the when I check it as *Yes* then it became more slower n the mobile Performance became **0%** how to speed up M2 store on Mobile?

Comment: magento version? did you read issues list , this shows you what needs to be fixed...